# Ошибка версий при подключении к БД

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Работаю с БД таким способом:

```php
<?php
$page = $_GET["page"];
mysql_connect("localhost", "login", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("aqqBD") or die(mysql_error());

$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM mydatabase LIMIT ".$page.",3";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

   echo $row['state']." - ".$row['date']." - ".$row['id']."<br>";

}
mysql_close();
```

Все выводит хорошо, но в `error_log` висит постоянно такая ошибка, как ее можно исправить?

> PHP Deprecated:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated
>   and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in ...

Если я начинаю использовать `mysqli_connect`, то появляется ошибка с `mysql_select_db`

Comment: зайди в доки http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php и прочитай надпись на красном фоне со слов **Внимание**. А  для mysqli используются методы, которые начинаются с `mysqli_`, а не `mysql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В свежих версиях PHP пора отказываться от mysql и переходить на mysqli.
Тебе намекают:

> use mysqli or PDO

Если используешь `mysqli_connect`, то используй и `mysqli_select_db`, а не `mysql_select_db`